$s(e+f) = e\lor f$ for projections $p,q\in B(H)$
Let $H$ be a Hilbert space and $p,q\in B(H)$ orthogonal projections, i.e.
$$p=p^*= p^2, \quad q=q^* = q^2.$$
I want to show that $s(p+q) = p\lor q$ where $s(p+q)$ is the support projection of $p+q$ and $p\lor q$ is the smallest projection dominating both $p$ and $q$. Note that I do not assume $p$ and $q$ to be orthogonal to each other, i.e. we do not have $pq=0$, so $p+q$ itself is not a projection. It is easy to see that
$$s(p+q)\le p \lor q.$$
However, I am not sure why the other 'inequality' holds.
Conceptually, the problem is that we want to be able to write
$$p\xi + q\eta = (p+q)\zeta$$
for a single $\zeta$ (depending on $\xi, \eta$) ( at least, up to closures) and it is not clear to me at all why this would be possible.
The claim I am trying to prove comes from p32 of the book "Lectures on von Neumann algebras" (second edition) by Stratila & Zsido: 
Thanks in advance for your help/comments!

The support projection of a self-adjoint element $x$ is the projection onto $(\ker x)^\perp$ and $p\vee q$ is the projection onto closed linear span of $pH\cup qH$. If you want to show $p\vee q\leq s(p+q)$, it suffices to show that $pH\cup qH\subset \ker(p+q)^\perp$. Since $p$ and $q$ are both positive, if $\xi\in \ker(p+q)$, then
$$
\lVert p\xi\rVert^2+\lVert q\xi\rVert^2=\langle \xi,(p+q)\xi\rangle=0,
$$
hence $\xi\in \ker p\cap \ker q$. The converse inclusion is obvious so that $\ker(p+q)=\ker p\cap \ker q$. Moreover, as $p$ and $q$ are projection, we have $pH\perp\ker p$ and $qH\perp \ker q$. This settles the claim.

Thanks a lot! Splendid answer.
